# rotate image every time imageview is clicked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have some imageviews that should rotate 90° every time they are touched. This is my code:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognize
{
    if (tapRecognize == tapRecognizer)
    {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);
        lineImage.transform = transform;
        [lineImage setTransform:transform];
    }    
}
```

This only rotate it first touch, how to I make it rotate 90° more when its taped again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first get the current transform of lineImage, then rotate that by 90 degrees. Following code will solve your problem

```
   - (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognize
    {
        if (tapRecognize == tapRecognizer)
        {
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(lineImage.transform, 90);
            [lineImage setTransform:transform];
        }
    }
```

and make sure you have enabled the uesr interaction of imageviews,

```
  [imageView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  [imageView2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```